# Why does wave interference occur?

Tags: waves, interference

**Elaborate question** : Wave interference is the interaction between 2 waves of the same frequency with varied amplitudes . They add up in case there is no phase difference and annihilate each other in case of phase differences. *Is there a specific reason why these 2 waves interfere the way they interfere ??*

Comment: You might get different answers for a [wave machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE520z_ugcU), and light.

Comment: why is that so , diffraction or any other phenomenon occurs for both light and wave ?

Answer (score 0):

At one location you can not speak of a wave it is just an oscillation, if this oscillation  has the same frequency and  the same time dependency they add ab to dooble the Amplitude, if on of them is behind  by half a time period they add up to 0
$Asin(\omega*t)+Asin(\omega*t)=2Asin(\omega*t) ; Asin(\omega*t)+Asin(\omega*(t-T/2)=0$

Comment: can u also explain the formula , how did you arrive this to this ?